# MS Access Subform conditional format based on data on a table

Tags: forms, ms-access, lookup, conditional-formatting, dlookup

My database has a Form view for the Lab to input the results of their tests to each batch we produce.
I have a query as Subform data source and I use a date combo box for the lab guys to see the production for the day. My problem is that when they write the value of the test (say batch 5, product A, test result= 10), I need the subform to do a conditional formatting based on a min/max specification located in another table. Say this table says product A allows a range from 11-15. Then when the technician writes 10, he should be prompted to quarantine the product. One easy way is to mark the CELL in BOLD RED.

This is my Subform layout:

```
Product | Batch #  |  Test result
```

My Spec sheet is something like this:

```
Product | Min | Max
```

I tried using `DLookup` without success, maybe the syntax is wrong.

Any recommendations on how to tackle this?

One nice idea that came through my mind would be to have a button to automatically notify my quality guy.

Thank you.

- Updated for easy understanding

Comment: Use a query as subform data source, then use product combobox as query criteria.

Comment: I have a query as Subform data source and I use a date combo box for the lab guys to see the production for the day. My problem is that when they write the value of the test (say batch 5, product A, test result= 10), I need the subform to do a conditional formatting based on a min/max specification located in another table. Say this table says product A allows a range from 11-15. Then when the technician writes 10, he should be prompted to quarantine the product. One easy way is to mark the CELL in BOLD RED.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you share a sample db so that we can have a look on it?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/35sq4vnroy7l3ad/to%20share.accdb?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autonumber ID field in Products is set as primary key yet the Product field in Batch is text. Change to number long integer type. This is correctly done in [Product Specification] table.

Once that field type is fixed, can include [Product Specification] table in LabBatchQuery and the specification fields will be available for direct reference in Conditional Formatting.

```
SELECT Batch.*, [Product Specification].*
FROM [Product Specification] RIGHT JOIN Batch ON [Product Specification].[Product Code] = Batch.Product
WHERE (((Batch.[Production Date])=[Forms]![TNA Batch Analysis]![Today Date]));
```

Change the RecordSource to simply reference LabBatchQuery instead of the SQL statement. Or instead of having dynamic parameter in the query object (I never do), put it in RecordSource SQL statement. `SELECT * FROM LabBatchQuery WHERE [Production Date]=[Forms]![TNA Batch Analysis]![Today Date];`

The Conditional Formatting rules will be like: `Value Is Not Between [pH Min] And [pH Max]`

Change the [Today Date] textbox AfterUpdate code to: `Me.[LabBatchQuery subform].Requery`

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Also recommend not setting lookups in tables.

If Products and [Product Specification] have 1-to-1 relationship, why not combine as 1 table?

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I have a lot to work on.... haha.... I fix one thing and I break 5.... After I fixed the fields to long integer type, all my queries broke. I fixed the references and then my Union query was showing the product id instead of product code. I fixed that by changing the bound column to 2 (in the lookup in the batch table). I see now what you mean about not using lookup in tables. haha... I have a lot to work on now. I will learn. Thank you for helping out

Comment: Am confused, changing BoundColumn to 2 means saving descriptive text; but if you changed Product field to number type, can't save alpha characters. And why would you have Product ID as Calculated field? Especially since it simply repeats ID field. And as for Production Date field, this is first time I have seen a date calculated from an identifier value, usually other way around. I recently encountered an issue where table calculated fields would not work in aggregate calcs on report, had to be fields calculated in query. Most experienced developers avoid table Calculated field type.

Comment: My product has to be a text because it is alpha numeric - example "TNA310S". I tried to change to integer, it would not allow me. As of why I have a Product ID as calculated field I can't answer. I really do not remember creating it unless I was stuck somewhere and I was trying to work around something. Full database is attached. https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5jh1h3ma3m5ez2/To%20Share%202.accdb?dl=0 - Use the START forms to navigate

Comment: Certainly, I expect that and is not what I suggested be changed. It is the primary key ID from Products that should be saved into Batch and [Product Specification] tables. You have done this for [Product Specification] but not Batch. So 'change' may have been misleading. Create number field in Batch and populate with the ID. Fix queries and delete the text field.

Comment: after I do this, will this query be editable? SELECT Batch.*, [Product Specification].*

Comment: Based on the first db I downloaded, yes. But don't allow the specification fields to be edited.

Comment: Very annoying, today the filter criteria is not working no matter where I put it. I swear it worked yesterday.

Comment: I could not make an editable query using both tables. So I did a work around. In the same form I have in the top the subform for the lab guy to fill the lab results. in the bottom I show another subform with the query where I could run Conditional Formatting.  The subform below is shows only the products that are out of spec.

Comment: Storing the ID value in number field in Batch table and linking on those number fields works for me. The query is definitely editable. I see you eliminated [Product Specifications] table and combined with Products but did not fix the foreign key field in Batch for product ID. If you want to link on Product text fields then change the primary key designation in Products table. The ID field is not being saved as foreign key therefore it should not be designated primary key. I did that change and query joining these tables is editable for me.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I will return to this first thing Jan 2nd and get in touch with my results.. thank you so much and happy new year

Comment: Can you send me what you did? I am not following the ID idea. All I did was follow many tutorials but never really messed with the Id in tables. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185928/discussion-between-june7-and-guilherme-brum).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`Form_BeforeUpdate`** to validate / conditional formatting the data

Below code will restrict PH values if they are out of range defined in Product Specification table. Similarly you can define for other fields.

Put this code to your subform:

---

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim pH_Min As Double, pH_Max As Double

    If Nz(Product, -1) <> -1 And Nz(Me.Batch__, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.pH, -1) <> -1 Then

        pH_Min = DLookup("[pH Min]", "Product Specification", "[Product Code]=" & Product)
        pH_Max = DLookup("[pH Max]", "Product Specification", "[Product Code]=" & Product)


        If Me.pH.Value >= pH_Min And Me.pH.Value <= pH_Max Then
            'no action
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Value", vbInformation
            Cancel = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @GuilhermeBrum Any Update on this ?